# In python how to use 'map' to create a batch of directories

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a batch of directories by using `map` like the following code, but it seems failed. Could you please help me?

```
import os
dir_list = ['./aaa', './bbb']
map(os.makedirs, dir_list)
```

I try `[os.makedirs(i) for i in dir_list]` and it succeeds, but I really want to know why `map` can not work.

Comment: First, what the heck is $may$? Second, don't. `map` is for transforming iterables, not for causing side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `map` returns a generator, which is lazily evaluated. That means `os.mkdirs` won't get called on each element of `dir_list` until the map object is iterated.

Here's the deal: neither `map` nor the list comprehension you've shown are intended to be used like this. They're to be used for transforming one sequence into another. They're *not* intended to be used with functions that *do things* (like create directories).

Just write a simple loop and don't try to be clever:

```
for d in dir_list:
    os.mkdirs(d)
```

This is correct, Pythonic, readable, and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathon Said:
In Python 3, map returns a generator, which is lazily evaluated. That means os.mkdirs won't get called on each element of dir_list until the map object is iterated.

so you need to iterate over the map object

you can do this hack:

```
 list(map(os.makedirs, dir_list))
```